# Application not receiving silent push notification after crash

Tags: ios, push-notification, ios9, uiapplicationdelegate

I have an application that has background mode of remote-notification enabled. If the app is running, the silent push notification comes in. Using the same payload `aps: {content-available : 1, sound :""}` if I trigger an app crash then send the silent push, it does not come through. I check a key in user default to see if the push came in. Once again it works fine if the app is active but not if crashed. Anyone have experience on what state an app is in after a crash and do silent pushes work?

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
    fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    NSString *action = userInfo[@"data"][@"action"];
    if(action && [action isEqualToString:@"exp-override"]){
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:userInfo[@"data"] forKey:@"exp_override2"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is the same situation when the app is killed by the user which the system [will not wake up the app](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:) even if the notification arrived.

Comment: I think according to the documentation for this method, when user force-quit the app, this method will not get called when receive notification. I think crash is similar to force-quit.

Comment: I know it won't respond when force quit by user. apples docs mention nothing about crash state. The docs say Apple will start the app when a silent comes in so I was hoping this would be the same with a crash state.